# In the sentence: "<noun> count" ("count of <noun>") should <noun> be plural or singular?

Tags: nouns, count

For instance, should I say: 1) "The book count is overwhelming" or 2) "(The?) Books count is overwhelming"? I am specifically interested in the version without "of" (as in brackets in the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sentences, "count" is the subject and "book" is an adjective. The verb and the definite article need to agree with "count" (i.e. without the adjective, you would say "The count is overwhelming," not "Count is overwhelming.").

There's no hard rule about whether a noun used as an adjective should be plural, but in most cases, the singular is used. "Book count" sounds much more natural than "books count" ([LD](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/can-a-plural-noun-act-as-an-adjective)).

**The book count is overwhelming.**

Comment: Can you, please, give an example of a sentence, where one would use plural adjective in the above scenario? Asking just out of the curiosity. (I still can't get use to thinking of "book" as an adjective, thou). I've noticed some examples under link you provided.

Comment: @Cromax You could say "the numbers game is overwhelming," for example, or "the media frenzy is overwhelming." Whether the plural or singular noun is used as an adjective depends on the noun it is paired with, not the rest of the sentence. As to "book" as an adjective, think "book club" or "book drive" or "book sales."